# Angular2: How to edit a field

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I'm building contact list app where user can add contact using input field like we normally do for getting data, I'm done with adding and delete contact but I'm confused with how will I edit added contact by clicking a button next to an added contact, The situation would be that I click on edit button and the contact will be in input field where I will edit the contact and click on update button and the edited contact will be there back in the list of contact, I may get -ve voting but I really want to see how would it be happen like contact back in input field for edit.

Here what I wrote for it its taking id as argument

```
updateparent(value){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.array.length ; i++){
    console.log('inside for');
    if(value == this.array[i].idobj){

        break;    
    }
}
```

What next after if? :)

HTML of parent:

```
<h1 class= "text-center">ToDo App</h1>
<div class = "form-group">
<lable>Task</lable>
<input name = "tasks" #task class = "form-control" >
<lable>Detail</lable>
<input type = "text" name = "taskdetail" #detail class = "form-control"  >
<button type = "submit" class  = "btn btn-default" 
(click) = "addtask(task, detail)">Add Task</button>
<child-component *ngFor = "#todo of array" 
[taskobject] = "todo"   (childevent) = "deleteparent($event)">
Loading...   </child-component>
</div>
```

HTML of child component to display data catched from parent :

```
{{taskobject.taskobj}}
{{taskobject.detailobj}}
{{taskobject.idobj}}
<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" 
(click) =   "deletetask(taskobject.idobj)">Delete</button>
<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-defualt"
(click) = "updatetask(taskobject.idobj)">Update</button>

`
```

Comment: Better you should use `ng-model` for this. Can you provide html also?

Comment: In Angular2 there is no `ng-model`, only `ngModel`. @flyingHawk please correct the tags to make it obvious what the question is about.

Comment: @parth I have included html file

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have included html file

Comment: @flyingHawk Your current code + description is not clear. So difficult to find make it easy to understand so other can help you.

Comment: No need to pass `task` here `"addtask(task, detail)"` if you are using `ng-model="taskdetail.task"`  you will an access values from Controller like `$scope.taskdetail`. and access single value as `$scope.taskdetail.task`. @flyingHawk

Comment: one thing more you are passing `task,detail` as arguments instead you have to send `task.value and detail.value` otherwise it will send `HTMLInputElement` to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `contact number` is just one value in the array then match the existing value for contact and when you got value of index( or i)
for the match just `splice` that value from the array and then update the new value in the array using push method. 
like this:

```
updateparent(value){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.array.length ; i++){
    console.log('inside for');
    if(value == this.array[i].idobj){
        this.array.splice(i,1);
        var newContact = value
        this.array.push(value);     
        break;    
    }
}
```

hope it help you ! if not provide plnkr code i will make it correct !

Comment: And what about getting into input field for edit, into HTML file

Comment: I have included html file

Comment: will you please provide plnkr for your code ? it would be easy to sort out the error for me !

Comment: Its ok to update record with new value push to array. For view you have to use `ng-model="taskdetail.taskdetail"` so in your scope when you update it set `$scope.taskdetail = value`. that will updated View also. @flyingHawk

Comment: firstly there is `ngModel`instead of `ng-model` secondly there is no $scope ...and if we talk about scope then whenever your array gets updated then automatically it sets new value and iterate new value set is't it ?

Comment: @PardeepJain check my comment i have mentioned `ng-model`.